# How to embed an image stored in Google Drive with Markdown?

Tags: markdown

I want to embed an image from Google Drive into a post using Markdown.

After searching I got the following two syntax hints, but if I copy and paste the url generated by the Google Drive's share option, it doesn't work.

```
Inline-style
![alt text](/url/to/img.jpg "Title")

Reference-style:
![alt text][id]
[id]: /url/to/img.jpg "Title"
```

I expected the image to be displayed in the post content.

Comment: well, what is the url then? also... please edit the profanities out...

Comment: I got it. After another searching I found out this: https://richardstudynotes.blogspot.com/2014/04/link-images-stored-in-google-drive-to.html

Answer (score 1):

for me, I followed this [post](https://help.codehs.com/en/articles/4616816-embedding-an-image-from-google-drive) and it works perfectly.

The markdown code:

```
<img align="left" width="400" height="350" 
src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=<YOUR-ID>">
```

Comment: Well, this is not Markdown. It's HTML

Answer (score 0):

No suggestion I found on the internet worked for me.

Seems like google does not want us to be able to do that.

The hack I found was using duckduckgo.com to show the image.

Try:

```
![test](https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fdrive.google.com/uc?id=<YOUR_ID>)
```